# What is most efficient way to find the sum of the series: (N/2^2)*2^2+(N/3^2)*3^2+(N/4^2)*4^2+........

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, number-theory, modular-arithmetic, linear-programming

I have been given a series:
$$\lfloor(N/2^2)\rfloor*2^2+\lfloor(N/3^2)\rfloor*3^2+\lfloor(N/4^2)\rfloor*4^2+....+\lfloor(N/\lfloor\sqrt(N)\rfloor^2)\rfloor*\lfloor\sqrt(N)\rfloor^2$$ 
Where N is a natural number. I know it can be solved in $O({\sqrt N})$ time complexity, but can there be any other way to solve this.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A309125

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times recently. I'm guessing it's a competition problem.